# nginx cache for reverse proxy with apache

Tags: apache, caching, nginx

i have a nginx web server with this cache configuration:

```
proxy_cache_valid         any 60m;
proxy_cache_path          /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my-cache:400m max_size=100m inactive=600m;
proxy_temp_path           /var/cache/nginx/tmp;
```

and my location cache is:

```
location / {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            # by vahid for proxy cache
            proxy_cache             my-cache;
            proxy_cache_valid       200 1d;
            proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Remote_addr $remote_addr;
            proxy_connect_timeout 90;
            proxy_send_timeout 90;
            proxy_read_timeout 420;
            client_max_body_size 100m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_buffer_size 4k;
            proxy_buffers 4 32k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
            root /var/www/html;
    }
```

in my nginx access log i see the requested file like this:

```
x.x.x.x - - [datetime] "GET /siY3Dh9_535.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 31157 HIT  0.004
```

this log says the request is hit and nginx no lookup apache but i get this request in apache access log. i think this is a problem.

this is apache access log sample: 
    127.0.0.1 - - [16/Dec/2013:10:02:31 +0330] "GET /siY3Dh9_535.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 -